# Store PHP error log file in the script directory without adding PHP code to existing scripts

Tags: php, error-handling

I have been busy setting up my own [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) after being used to [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel), but I can't seem to find out how to let PHP create an *error_log* file in the same directory as the script that throws the errors.

I would like this to happen without me having to add a line of code to each .php file. In cPanel this works out of the box somehow.

Example:

Error in:  `/var/www/webapp1/index.php` 
Logfile location: `/var/www/webapp1/error_log`

Error in:  `/var/www/info/system/test.php` 
Logfile location: `/var/www/info/system/error_log`

Basically, I want PHP to store an *error_log* file in each directory for the scripts in that directory.

Additional information:

- Single VPS account
- [Debian 6.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_6.0_(Squeeze)) (Squeeze) GNU/Linux
- Apache 2.2.16

Comment: Since you commented on two answers, perhaps accept an answer to indicate which one answered your question?

Answer (score 4):

Set the `error_log` value to the name of the error log you want to appear in the directory, but do not put any slashes. The file will be saved in the directory from which the script is ran, so the same directory.

```
error_log = "php_error.log"
```

Answer (score 2):

For this, there is the `error_log` directive in php.ini like:

```
error_log string
```

Where string represents the name of the file where script errors should be logged. The file should be writable by the web server's user. If the special value syslog is used, the errors are sent to the system logger instead. On Unix, this means syslog(3) and on Windows NT it means the event log. The system logger is not supported on Windows 95. See also: [syslog()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php). If this directive is not set, errors are sent to the SAPI error logger. For example, it is an error log in Apache or stderr in CLI.

Comment: that still does not answer my question, how can I set it to save the error log in the same directory as the php script for each different directory like Cpanel does?

Comment: well - you got to give us a little more details - OS used, you mentioned VPS - do you have a VPS for every user/application? What webserver do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Edit your *php.ini* file and uncomment the line with [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log):

```
error_log = php_errors.log
```

Save the changes, restart Apache, and be happy.

If you're **using Linux**, open a terminal and type this to restart:

```
sudo services apache2 restart
```

If you have access to [WebHost Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel#WHM) (WHM) you can search for SERVICES and then restart HTTPD or Apache.

If you're using [EasyPHP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyPHP) or **[Vertrigo](https://www.vswamp.com/)**, you can do that through the program it self.

Answer (score 1):

> basically I want php to store an error_log file in each directory for the scripts in that directory

Assuming you're using Apache, you can use Apache's error_log directive in the VirtualHost to accomplish this behaviour. If memory serves me right, PHP itself doesn't decide where it stores its errors.

Comment: that still does not answer my question, how can I set it to save the error log in the same directory as the php script for each different directory like Cpanel does?